# Why dont akka actors have a postStart method?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Here is a situation i have to deal with -
I am using websockets with play framework and each websocket connection has its own `Actor` as described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWebSockets). Now as soon as the websocket connection is made i need to start another `Actor` that subscribes to a `Redis` channel and on getting any published message to the channel passes that message to its parent i.e the `Websocket Actor`. So i need to start the `Redis Subscriber Actor` after the `Websocket Actor` has started. But actors dont have a `postStart` method. I tried creating the `Redis Subscriber Actor` in the `preStart` method of the `Websocket Actor` and it works fine but i dont understand the reason for `Actors` not having a `postStart` method. Isn't this a common scenario where actors create children actors. Or is this approach of doing things incorrect?

Comment: Not sure why `preStart` is not sufficient for your needs, it's one good place to put child actor creation (the other being the constructor body).  The thing about `preStart` is that it really means pre message handling.  The actor itself has been started up but is not yet receiving messages from the mailbox.  This is a good place to make sure any other dependencies are created before you start handling messages.  If you did this after the actor started handling messages you could hit a race condition where the dependency (child) is not created yet.

Comment: @cmbaxter I think that might as well be the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, I'm not sure why `preStart` is not sufficient for your needs, it's one good place to put child actor creation (the other being the constructor body). The thing about `preStart` is that it really means pre message handling. The actor itself has been started up but is not yet receiving messages from the mailbox. This is a good place to make sure any other dependencies are created before you start handling messages. If you did this after the actor started handling messages you could hit a race condition where the dependency (child) is not created yet

You should review the actor lifecycle diagram [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/scala/actors.html) for more clarity